# Adding widget depending on state

Tags: flutter, dart, state

At the very beginning, I would like to sorry to you all for the stupid questions but I'm dumb if it takes me to programming and I'm a newbie.

I am making simple pomodoro app. I have a problem. I would like to add these circle things:

[image]

depending on state. I mean if rounds == 1 than show only first colored circle, if rounds == 2 show first and second colored cirlce and so on.

Could someone help me?
Here is the code that I use for this circle thing.

```
Expanded(
  child: Container(
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 10,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      shape: BoxShape.circle,
      color: color,
      border: Border.all(
        color: borderColor,
        strokeAlign: StrokeAlign.outside,
        width: 3,
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_rating_bar with your custom circle icon. If you make half rating parameter. You can also wrap it with IgnorePointer widget to prevent user hands:)

Answer (score 0):

You need to track the current number, and color will be changed based on it.

```dart
color: currentNumber >= i + 1
    ? Colors.red
    : Colors.transparent,
```

Test snippet

```dart
class Appx extends StatefulWidget {
  const Appx({super.key});

  @override
  State<Appx> createState() => _AppxState();
}

class _AppxState extends State<Appx> {
  int currentNumber = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            children: [
              for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                Expanded(
                  child: AnimatedContainer(
                    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 10,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                      color: currentNumber >= i + 1
                          ? Colors.red
                          : Colors.transparent,
                      border: Border.all(
                        color: Colors.red,
                        strokeAlign: StrokeAlign.outside,
                        width: 3,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
            ],
          ),
          Slider(
            max: 5,
            value: currentNumber.toDouble(),
            divisions: 5,
            onChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {
                currentNumber = value.toInt();
              });
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```